# Netbeans IDE setting for advanced file dialog

Tags: netbeans

I've installed a new version of Netbeans (6.8) and can't remember how to change the File/Project open dialogs to the "advanced" view.  (Argh!!)

Anyone know where to look?

Classic view (what I have):
[image: Classic mode]

Advanced(?) view (what I want):
[image: Classic mode]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you don't have a plugin installed in the other version?  Select

Tools->Plugins

then click the installed tab.

Your preferences are under Tools->Options.

Comment: Thanks.  It was the "Quick File Chooser" plugin.  To see it, I had to click the "show details" checkbox in the installed tab.